# Tesseract problem with mftraining stage

Tags: tesseract

I've successfully created a box file with tesseract 
now after running the unicharset_extractor 
having it creating the unicharset file that looks like:

```
...
n 3 NULL -1
s 3 NULL 23
t 3 NULL 43
...
```

I've continued with this command

```
mftraining -U unicharset -O testlang.unicharset testlang.tr
```

only to get the next error

```
Reading testlang.tr ...
testlang has no defined properties.

Error: Illegal short name for a feature!
```

Comment: Those NULLs are part of the expected output of the unicharset file?

Comment: Did you ever get this answered? I am having the same question.

Answer (score 0):

I've never worked with Tesseract, but it seems there is an open issue in the bug database that looks a lot like your problem : http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/issues/detail?id=385

It seems that it is related to scientific notation not being correctly supported by some functions.

On the issue page a user suggests a solution, and another one proposes a patch. You could try applying the patch to see if it helps.

Comment: oops, didn't notice that, my bad.